# API Youtube, no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, http-headers, youtube-api

I'm developping a web extension available on Chrome and Firefox. This extension use the fetch javascript method to extract datas from 2 APIs, Youtube API and Twitch API. 
When i launch the request, i saw different response headers on Chrome compare to Firefox. However, this difference, break my extension on Firefox. I need a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on the response headers and i only have it on Chrome and not on Firefox, i do not understand why !

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin) they say that they need an 'Origin' field in the header request to provide the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' in the response. I have the right header but not the right response.

This is my code for the fetch method:

```
/**
 * Obtientla promesse de donnée Youtube
 * 
 * @method _getYoutubeDatasPromise
 * @returns {Promise}
 * @private
 */
_getYoutubeDatasPromise() {

    const headers = new Headers();

    return fetch(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=${YT_key}&channelId=${YT_UserId}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=2`,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: headers
        }
    )
};
```

This is the request / response headers:

[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVmK7.png)  | [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhTBR.png)

And this is the error log in console on Firefox :

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jPa9.png)

Thanks for your help ! :)

EDIT: The manifest.json :

```
{
"name": "HuzLive",
"version": "0.1",
"description": "Soyez toujours au courant des lives & vidéos de votre streameur Dofus préféré",
"permissions": ["activeTab", "notifications", "storage"],
"background": {
    "page": "background.html"
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/huz_logo16.png",
        "32": "images/huz_logo32.png",
        "48": "images/huz_logo48.png",
        "128": "images/huz_logo128.png"
    }
},
"icons": {
    "16": "images/huz_logo16.png",
    "32": "images/huz_logo32.png",
    "48": "images/huz_logo48.png",
    "128": "images/huz_logo128.png"
},
"applications": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "{b8e90417-1550-474f-bd6e-de91b8382298}",
      "strict_min_version": "42.0"
    }
  },
"manifest_version": 2
```

}

Comment: I believe you'll need to add a permission in the `manifest.json` of your extension - please include the `manifest.json` of your firefox web extension in the question - or read this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions#Host_permissions) - you should never need CORS headers in an extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I believe you'll need to add a permission in the manifest.json of your extension - please include the manifest.json of your firefox web extension in the question - or read this documentation - you should never need CORS headers in an extension – Jaromanda X

I found the answer ! I forgot to put api domains in the permission of my manifest.json !

i just add :

```
"permissions": ["https://api.twitch.tv/*", "https://www.googleapis.com/*", "activeTab", "notifications", "storage"]
```

Thanks a lot !!